Cannot connect to Keycloak Server
I am using the python-keycloak library 3.3 to connect my python app with Keycloak. I am using 2 clients in 1 realm. On my local computer, when I run the keycloak server on localhost:8080 it works perfect, but when I try to connect to the Keycloak Server, deployed in an Azure cloud I get this error for the auth client:
keycloak.exceptions.KeycloakConnectionError: Can't connect to server (Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: True)
For the other client which I need for my frontend and here is no TLS CA certificate issue and I can reach the server without any problems.
Can someone help me?
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenIDConnection
from config import cfg

cdb = cfg['test']

keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(
                        server_url=['SERVER_URL'],
                        username=cdb['USERNAME'],
                        password=cdb['PASSWORD'],
                        realm_name=cdb['REALM_NAME'],
                        client_id=cdb['CLIENT_ID'],
                        client_secret_key=cdb['CLIENT_SECRET_KEY'],
                        verify=cdb['VERIFY'])

keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)


You can't make a direct child realm's connection. You connect the master realm first
And switch child realm.
I don't know why. It works the old Keycloak version but not work v24.
Launch Keycalok
Launch Keyclock by docker-compose in here
configuration
config.py
master realm and credential
test  = dict(
    SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8080',
    MASTER_USERNAME = 'admin',
    MASTER_PASSWORD = 'admin',
    MASTER_REALM_NAME = 'master',
    MASTER_CLIENT_ID = 'admin-cli',
    REALM_NAME = 'my-realm',
    VERIFY = True
)

demo.py
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenIDConnection
import config

cdb = config.test

keycloak_connection = KeycloakOpenIDConnection(
                        server_url=cdb['SERVER_URL'],
                        username=cdb['MASTER_USERNAME'],
                        password=cdb['MASTER_PASSWORD'],
                        realm_name=cdb['MASTER_REALM_NAME'],
                        client_id=cdb['MASTER_CLIENT_ID'],
                        verify=cdb['VERIFY']
)

keycloak_admin = KeycloakAdmin(connection=keycloak_connection)

keycloak_admin.change_current_realm(cdb['REALM_NAME'])

current = keycloak_admin.get_current_realm()
print('current realm : ' + current)

users = keycloak_admin.get_users()
for user in users:
  print(user)

Result


Thank you very much! Very strange that it works only through the master realm, but is this safe because there is no client_secret_key in the admin-cli client?

I am not sure more safe or not, master credential more higher credential. I think more unsafe this situation.

Ok I figured it out, you cannot use verify=cdb['VERIFY'] because then it takes 'True' as a string but it needs a boolean. It works with child realm as well, no need for using the master realm and changing to the child realm.
